# How to handle multiple listeners with same argument in google guava eventbus

Tags: java, guava, event-bus

I have two  listener that will accept same argument for when  posting events into eventbus.But even though accept same argument  those listeners are behave differently.

```
public class EventListener1 {



    @Subscribe
    public void executeJob(jobVO jobVO ) {
        //logic goes here
    }
}



public class EventListener2 {



    @Subscribe
    public void cancelJob(jobVO jobVO ) {
        //logic goes here but different
    }
}

EventBus eventBus = new EventBus();
eventBus.register(new EventListener1());
eventBus.register(new EventListener2());
```

user press  execute button and wants to trigger `EventListener1` like wise for cancel job.

**for execute job**

```
JobVO j=new JobVO();
j.setAction("executeJob");
etc... 
eventBus.post(j);
```

**for cancel job**

```
JobVO j=new JobVO();
j.setAction("cancelJob");
etc... 
eventBus.post(j);
```

My question is that how can i trigger specific listener when  posting events into eventbus or it will call both listeners?

Comment: Can't you use some specific subclasses like `class ExecuteJob extends JobVO` etc?

Comment: @RC. can not we use JobVO as client server communication.in web tier we create jobVO from user  inputs and pass into server.i know this can  be easy if use sub classes.i just want to know is there any other way to do it instead of using sub classes.Thanks.

Comment: one event listener and a switch will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some simple solutions:

```
@Subscribe
public void executeJob(jobVO jobVO ) {
    if (!jobVO.getAction().equals("executeJob")) {
       return;
    }
    //logic goes here
}
```

...or, alternately, *don't use EventBus*:

```
JobVO j=new JobVO();
j.setAction("executeJob");
etc... 
eventListenerForExecuting.executeJob(j);
```